# Mysql/C# error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, datareader

I have a piece of code to execute a mysqlcommand but sometimes it throws the exception

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

It is unpredictable when the exception will be throw sometimes my program works fine for over 15min but then it craches. I looked online for an answer but i didn't find anything.
This is my code:

```
 public static List<string> DoCommand(string commandLine, string myConString) {
             MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandLine);
            List<string> tables = new List<string>();
            try {
                using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConString)) {
                    mySqlConnection.Open();
                    command.Connection = mySqlConnection;
                    command.BeginExecuteReader();
                    using (MySqlDataReader SqlDR = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                        while (SqlDR.Read()) {  //Async reading, wait untill reading is done
                            tables.Add(SqlDR.GetString(0));
                        }
                        //SqlDR.Close();
                        //SqlDR.Dispose();
                    }
                    //mySqlConnection.Close();
                    //mySqlConnection.Dispose();
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) { } finally {
                command.Connection = null;
            }
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);     //Give connection time to flush
            return tables;
        }
```

there are some of the solutions that didn't work in comment.
This is the only code taht connects to mysql so i am sure all connections are closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you above code is what you intended, this line is not required:

```
  command.BeginExecuteReader();
```

The [SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx) Method:

> Initiates the asynchronous execution
>   of the Transact-SQL statement or
>   stored procedure that is described by
>   this SqlCommand, and retrieves one or
>   more result sets from the server

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
using (MySqlDataReader SqlDR = command.ExecuteReader())
```

with

```
using (MySqlDataReader SqlDR = command.EndExecuteReader()
```